# is there a way to have np.where skip any strings that contain non numerics?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I'm attempting to convert a column inside a dataframe from percentage int into categorical. Using np.where I can bucket it once. Any additional attempts the further split the data fails due to int being converted to a str.
I can't figure out how to skip strings with words that can't be converted to ints.
While (x).astype(int) works for '26' it throws a base 10 error for 'low'

What I'm trying to do:

`life_data = [10, 50, 95, 19, 89]` (actually a csv file I'm importing)

first pass works; all data is converted from int to str

`life_data = np.where(life_data < 50, 'low', life_data)`

`print(life_data)`

`['low', '50', '95', 'low', '89']`

Next attempt fails due to the word 'low' attempting to be converted to an int, throws base 10 error

`life_data = np.where(50 >= life_data.astype(int) < 91, 'mid', life_data)`

expected output (but fails)
`['low', 'mid', '95', 'low', 'mid']`

also fails when trying to omit 'low' with **and** truth value error. I've attempted to use a.any() or a.all() and can't seem to wrap it correctly.

`life_data = np.where(life_data != low and 50 >= life_data.astype(int) < 91, 'mid', life_data)`

expected output (but fails)
`['low', 'mid', '95', 'low', 'mid']`

Comment: Have a look at `np.select` (or use nested `np.where`) that way you can specify 'low', 'mid'` and presumably 'high', in a single call which avoids all of this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid errors during numeric parsing, try

```py
pd.to_numeric(['low', 'mid', '95', 'low', 'mid'], errors='coerce')
```

Output

```
[nan, nan, 95., nan, nan]
```

You'll find the cut function useful.

```py
life_data = pd.Series([10, 50, 95, 19, 89])
pd.cut(life_data, right=False,
       bins=[0, 50, 91, np.inf],
       labels=['Low', 'Med', 'High'])
```

Output

```
0     Low
1     Med
2    High
3     Low
4     Med
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should work:

Before you use np.where(), add an if statement that says

```
if ![insert your string here].isnumeric():
        [insert handling code here]
```